# Call array to asembler function

Tags: arrays, assembly, call

I have solution in Visual Studio 2008, GUI in C# and project with assembler function. I go on each pixel on image and store it in array. For example i have image 100x100 so i make array[99][99] and put into RGB values.

```
Bitmap copiedBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
```

Now I have assembler function(MASM) in my C# project and I want send this array to assembler. I want call like this:

```
Bitmap x = assembly(copiedBitmap);
```

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/unmanage.aspx

Comment: Not quite this, **assembly** is a function written in assembler i have access to it because I have :
[DllImport("Assembly.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern Bitmap assembly(Bitmap original);

Comment: So you are calling dll function?

Comment: I used this - [link](http://translate.google.pl/translate?hl=pl&sl=pl&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fipij.aei.polsl.pl%2Farticle.php%3Fid%3D36)